# Why didn't Naruto do anything when he and Gaara were being beaten by the ressurected leader?

Tags: naruto

In season 4 episodes 219-220 of the original *Naruto*, when Naruto and Gaara were being beaten by the resurrected leader, why didn’t Naruto release the power of the nine-tailed fox? Why did he almost die and yet nothing happened? He was one of the weakest people in this fight.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. I tried to clarify the title based on the question body, but I might be wrong in saying "didn't do anything" because I'm not following the series. It'd be better if you [edit] the title to represent the question correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because that whole arc was filler. Additionally it was a filler arc directed to Gaara, his student and his change. You can say he was the main character, Naruto the side character therefore he was the one who needed to defeat the "bad" guy. If he released the power of the nine-tails I highly doubt Gaara would had the time to shine like he did at the end. Seimei would have been beaten by Naruto.

There is no other reasonable explanation given to us in this arc why he didn't/couldn't use it. You could say it was due to plot.